# Как растянуть блок по высоте картинки?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css3, frontend

Есть блок, внутри которого картинка. Нужно сделать высоту по картинке.
Танцую вокруг него уже 2 день, помогите.

[image: https://beautyprosoftware.com/ru/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE-2/]

```
<div class="img-box height-240">
<div class="background">
<div class="layer" style="background-image: url(images/background/layer-78.jpg);">
<img width="560" height="315" src="https://****.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="****.jpg 560w, ****.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 560px) 100vw, 560px">                                          
</div></div>
```

СSS

```
    .blog-post .img-box.height-240 {
    min-height: 240px;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.blog-post .img-box {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}   
.blog-post img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;

}

.blog-post img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Если поставить высоту картинки 100%, а не auto, то картинку сожмет в этом блоке с высотой 240px!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте flex. В примере ниже - минимальный код для картинки в картинке.

```css
.layer {
  height: 240px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.layer img {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer" style="background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/room-with-modern-paintings_1048-2469.jpg);">
  <img width="560" height="315" src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/e2/98/graffiti_letters_font_text_decoration_painted_wall_art-1389489.jpg!d" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 560px) 100vw, 560px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

блок в блоке и т д. Некоторые блоки имеют абсолютное позиционированние. Нужно, чтобы просто был див, внутри которого картинка, которая имеет стили: width: 100%; height: auto. При таких расклидах такая картинка всегда будет оптимизироваться под ширину,. А еще у тебя в некоторых блоках overflow: hidden - этот стиль  обрезает все, что не влезло
у верхнего блока убери минимальную и максимальную высоту (img-box )

у блока .background убери: высоту, оверфлоу, а позишн поставь static

у .layer убери оверфлоу и позишн

у самого изображения убери позишн, сделай его статичным
 вроде так.
 там не нужно вкладывать блок в блок. просто img вложи в блок. блок не делай абсолютным. потому, что когда он абсолютный, но без указанной высоты, то его высота будет 0, если картинка тоже абсолютная. А настройка overflow: hidden обрежет все, что не поместилось

```
 <div простой див, без указания высоты>
<img style="width: 100%; height: auto" src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

этому диву пожно указать ширину. Чтобы внутри еще кнопки аюсолютные были, дай этому диву position: relative
 и проблем не будет

Answer (score 0):

Указать

```
img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]